# How do I Plan a Hiking Trip to Rocky Mountain National Park, CO

Tags: hiking, preparation, backcountry

I need some help planning a a hiking trip to CO. I have been on a couple of hiking trips and have grown up going into the mountains with my family but I have never been the one to plan a trip. I'm confident packing for the trip, I know what I will need as far as food and clothing. What I really need help on is reserving camp sites, planing my hike, and working everything out with the park. It is maybe a simple thing but I want to make sure I do everything right.

I'm planning on going to the Rocky Mountain National Park and I was thinking June or July. I was going to try and reserve camp sites now because I know that is a busy time of year. I think the park saves some sites for walk ups, has anyone done this?

Comment: Will you hike carrying everything on your back? Or rather have a base and make day hikes? Sleeping in tents or in huts?

Comment: We will carry everything in our packs. We would like to hike a loop, moving camp every night.

Comment: If you're backpacking, I'd give consideration to avoiding RMNP and looking at the many wilderness areas immediately around it. Wilderness areas are often less busy, often better suited to backpackers, and often cheaper or free, with no designated campsites. Different wilderness areas have different styles of scenery.

Comment: @whatsisname that is a good idea. Do you have any Wilderness areas you would recommend? We where hoping to see the continental divide, and maybe a lake or two.

Comment: @JaredChristensen: I do not know any in that area, however I am going to be doing some backpacking in that area in sept, after a wedding, so I can tell you then :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to reserve your campsite in advance. If you are thinking about camping in the backcountry areas, you will need a permit, and it's advisable to consult with a ranger concerning your travel plans. As far as planning your hikes, it's best to visit this [Rocky Mountain National Park](http://rockymountainnationalpark.com/trails-maps) website.

Comment: Great link, this helps.

Comment: Thanks I called and booked my campsites. Was easier then I thought.